# Getting duplicate entries on multiple sed runs

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, sh

I am using the following `sed` command to get rid of duplicates

But it is still causing duplicate entries on multiple runs

```
sed -i '/^text1/i\value=value+1' file.txt | uniq
```

Here `uniq` is not helping to get rid of duplicate entries

Comment: If you are trying to do math and operate a counter, I don't believe `value=value+1` is working as you expect with `sed`. You should probably supply a MCVE. It will help the folks providing answers. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You've been a SO member for over 3 years and asked 193 questions so far so I'd think by now you should know what it takes to ask a question on this forum but if not see [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that an example file might help, and that was my first thought too. But if you look at the code it's quite clear what happens.

Comment: @hek2mgl I've been bit too many times trying to figure out what someone wants by reading code that DOESN'T do what they want. Even when I'm sure I understand what they're trying to do I'm only right about half the time! In this I can imagine a few possibilities but I really just don't know what it is the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you run `sed -i`, `sed` won't output anything to stdout. That's why piping to `uniq` is useless.

---

Second, `uniq` needs the input to be sorted to work:

```
sed ... file.txt | sort | uniq > file.txt.tmp
mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

You can also use the `-u` flag of `sort`:

```
sed ... file.txt | sort -u > file.txt.tmp
mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

---

If the order of lines must be preserved, you could use `awk`:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++{next} /^text1/{print "value=value+1";print}' file.txt > file.txt.tmp
mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

Btw, GNU awk comes with a way to modify files in place nowadays:

```
gawk -i inplace 'seen[$0]++{next} /^text1/{print "value=value+1";print}' file.txt
```